# "query values must be an array"...?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

As the title reads, I am receiving a "query values must be an array" error when writing Node.js code to attempt to query a local (postgres) database.  Here is the code I am using:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://user:pass@localhost:5432/mydatabase";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);

client.connect(function(err) {
  if(err) {
    return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
  }
  client.query('SELECT $1::text AS name', 'howdy', function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      return console.error('error running query', err);
    }
    console.log(result.rows[0].name);
    client.end();
  });
});
```

I believe this refers to the need to have the query string use array values rather than a direct string...however I am unsure how to structure the code.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I thank you in advance.  Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is right. The second parameter to `query` should be an array. This is a [`paramterized query`](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query)

```
client.query('SELECT $1::text AS name', ['howdy'] ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I made the correction you suggested.  It does not give me any error any longer...however the term 'howdy' is printed in my console log...I do not understand why that would be the case...the word does not appear in my database...the string in the brackets (i.e. ['howdy']) is the string I wish to be searched in the database...correct?  Can I refine the search to a certain table?  Such as: 'SELECT $1::text FROM users AS name', ['howdy']...   ?   Thanks again.

Comment: I am trying to query the database to 'search' for user name and password information...I do not understand why the word 'howdy' is returned and printed in the console if it does not appear in the database.  Could I write something like "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name', ['howdy'] ...?

Comment: something like this `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=$1, ['bob']`?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  I got an "permission denied for relation users" error...however I believe that is an error dealing with table access privileges therefore it would seem the query actually executed...thank you for your help...very much appreciated.